# Unit testing a PHP Framework

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have a custom Lightweight PHP framework that our company uses. To start, I don't want the suggestion to use a third-party framework. I am trying to write unit tests for it but I have stumbled upon a problem. I am relatively new to unit testing, but most of the code is already covered.

I have a loader class that will require files that can't be loaded with a class auto loader (e.g. Configuration files). It has a kind of fallback system where if you don't specify a module to load a particular resource from, it will try to guess based on the current module, then the default module. This has required me (so far as I can see) to check for the existence of a particular file before falling back to the default.

The problem I'm running into is writing a test for the class that doesn't actually depend on any files existing (which is obviously desirable). I've read about virtual file systems and testing, but I'm having trouble seeing how I can utilize it to solve my problem.

I can write an abstraction of the filesystem that I inject into this class, but then that class will have a similar problem.

In pseudo code: if file exists in this module, load it; if not, load the default.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
class Base implements Loader {

...

protected function _include( $type, $name ){
    $identifier = $this->parseName($name);

    $path = '/'.$this->resource_types[$type]['directory'].'/'.$this->resource_types[$type]['file_prefix'].$identifier['name'].'.php';

    if( $identifier['module'] && is_file(Core::basePath().'/'.Constant::get('MODULE_PATH').'/'.$identifier['module'].$path) ){
        Core::requireRoot('/'.Constant::get('MODULE_PATH').'/'.$identifier['module'].$path);

    } else if( is_file(Core::basePath().'/'.Constant::get('CORE_PATH').$path) ){
        Core::requireRoot('/'.Constant::get('CORE_PATH').$path);

    } else {
        throw new Exceptions\Load(ucwords($type).' '.$name.' not found');
    }
}

....

}
```

This is a very low-level class, so it has a few static calls that are basically substitutes for or wrappers around native PHP functions. `Core::requireRoot` is just a wrapper around the native `require` function.  `Constant::get` is a custom implementation of constants (an alternative to `define`, then using the constant directly). Keep in mind I'm not actually testing this method directly. I have public methods such as `loadHooks` that I am actually testing that call this method behind the scenes.

Comment: Testing very much depends on the ability to mock dependencies. If a piece of code has such hardcoded dependencies that they can't be mocked, the code is simply hard/impossible to test. In that case some actual code sample would help to see if there's indeed nothing to hook into.

Comment: I think you are right , though the dependencies you are talking about are native php functions. I can write an abstraction of the file system and inject that. But I still have to figure out how to determine which file was required.

Comment: Trying to emulate a file system is going way too low for a unit test. Your code should use an abstraction to get the config files. Something like a `Config` class which you inject into the code, and the code uses `$config->get('foo.bar')` to load those files. That's easily mockable. A hardcoded `fopen('config/foo/bar')` is virtually impossible to mock.

Comment: Maybe http://kunststube.net/static can lend some more perspective here.

Comment: I will think about that but it doesn't seem to get around the issue I've presented (then again maybe I am going about it the wrong way and have everything contained in a class). But to be clear, when I say configuration files I'm talking about more than your example. I'm talking About files that define and attach hooks to the application, etc.

Comment: I don't see how that article is remotely relevant. When did I say anything about using statics? I know what dependency injection is.

Comment: In summary: if you want to unit test your code, you need to write *unit testable* code. You can't mock what you can't mock. The point of linking to that article was because it talks about *coupling* and *dependencies*.

Comment: Still don't see how that's relevant, but it's partially my fault because I haven't posted any code. Give me a minute.

Comment: If it doesn't help, ignore it. I don't know what you know, so I'm just offering hints in the general direction.

Comment: I understand it's hard to answer without any code. Check out my edit, if you like.

Comment: Seeing how you're using static calls all over the place, I don't see how the above article is *not* relevant. :P

Comment: start unit tests with simple hello world classes. If you feel familar with PHPUnit than start to test your framework

Comment: Maybe you didn't read that they are simply wrappers around native php functions.

Comment: Besides, those are not the problem. The problems are the calls to `is_file`.

Comment: @hek2mgl I am using PHPUnit and I have done plenty more than hello worlds already. :)

Comment: So where is your actual test code that does not work? Will fix this

Comment: @hek2mgl The problem is that I don't know **how** to test whether the right files would be included if the don't actually exist (otherwise to test different cases you would actually have to create, write to, and unlink the files for the test, which has all kinds of potential issues). I don't really want someone to write it for me. I'm more looking for suggestions. I think virtual filesystems may help, but that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you ask me, you could/should refactor the code in a way that this testing problem will went away.. Another possible way to got would be to either create the file temporary for testing, or mock the file system using [vfs stream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/)

Comment: @hek2mgl That's funny, because I was prompted to write this post after researching a bit about VFS Stream. I don't think I can refactor to get testing it out of the way. I can create an abstraction of the filesystem which I inject into this class, but then that class becomes untestable for the same reasons (so far as I can tell, which is why I wrote this post). I may just have to bite the bullet and leave the framework untested somewhere. Thank you for your constructive feedback .

Comment: @RyanWilliams Have a day in the outdoors, or two.. I'm sure you'll find once a way how code can be either refactored or tested..

Comment: @hek2mgl Haha. I guess I'm trying to skip that part with this post. :)

Comment: @RyanWilliams Maybe this helps.. My autoloader has 100% test coverage.. https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Autoloader ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl This is more along the lines of what I'm looking for (an example). I will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @hek2mgl I see you're using temporary files, but it's not as painful as I would have thought. I will give this consideration. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both to @hek2mgl and (to a lesser extent) @deceze (who was correct about my static calls), I have a solution to this problem. It is not the kind of solution I originally hoped for, but I think it's the best that can be done. Here goes.

I am going to use temporary files, as per @hek2mgl's suggestion here (github.com/metashock/Jm_Autoloader). I don't think there is any way around this, even with a filesystem abstraction object. That said, I **am** going to use a filesystem abstraction object which I'll inject into this class, because it will make it easier to re-use the temporary file substitution in other contexts.

I am going to remove the static calls in that function (which I knew better than to do, but it can be easy to convince yourself that "this is such a low-level class it actually doesn't matter"). Instead I will create getter and setter methods for the CORE_PATH and MODULES_PATH, and revert to native call to require. This does not need to be done with a new filesystem object, but I think it is a lot cleaner and more flexible, and more loosely coupled.